# How to find icon names (to add to theme)

Tags: themes, icons

I'm creating an icon theme, but I'm running into trouble adding new icons. I'm starting by building off of an existing theme, so if there's an icon already there I just replace the one with the right file name. But I can't figure out what I need to name icons I'm adding for programs that aren't already in the theme. Where can I find the names for icons for individual programs?

Comment: all icons are located in /usr/share/icons pick an icon theme and check the icons. You can edit icon with other one for example `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop` change the `icon=` string providing path to a new image or move your new icon to /usr/share/icons and name it/replace it as firefox.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I was looking for, and also explains why some of the icons weren't getting changed when I added a new icon to the theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As my comment appeared a good explanation for you I converted it into answer with some editions.

As stated all icons are located in `/usr/share/icons/nameoftheme` pick an icon theme and check the icons in apps folder. You can edit icon with other one for example:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

Change the `icon=` string providing a path to a new image or move your new icon to `/usr/share/icons/nameoftheme` and name it `firefox`.

The same if some of your apps is missing an icon provided by theme probably because it doesn't have such icon name, for example Guayadeque Music Player usually missing its new icon when new theme is applied instead original icon is used. What you can do is to check Guayadeque icon command with e.g.:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/guayadeque.desktop
```

or directly:

```
cat /usr/share/applications/guayadeque.desktop | grep -i icon
```

if it says:

```
icon=guayadeque
```

Go to the theme folder and you can rename some music icon or create new one with the name `guayadeque` if it doesn't allow you to create a new one then run Nautilus with `sudo` priveleges `gksudo nautilus`.

Do mention to name icon format if you providing a path to it manually otherwise it won't take effect for example if it `.svg`:

```
icon=/home/admin/pictures/guayadeque.svg
```

or if the icon is present in current theme folder then simply:

```
icon=guayadeque
```

To list your desktop applications that you can edit or etc you can use `ls` command:

```
ls /usr/share/applications/*
```

Comment: You don't need /usr/share/icons/nameoftheme if you have changed the theme in Unity Tweak. Then you just need the name `firefox` as the icon.

Comment: yes it's true I just explained all possible variants. ;)

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry :) Read it all now!